# Install old zip package

Tags: miktex

I'm a newcomer in the LaTeX world and I'm struggling while trying to install and old zip pluggin with MikTex 2.9.

The pluggin is the following:

https://ctan.org/pkg/morse

Can someone help me please ?

Regards,

Hervé Jacquemin

Comment: Use the MikTeX package manager to install packages.

Comment: The `morse` package is not included in the MiKTeX distribution (it has a non-free license). Therefore you cannot install it with the MiKTeX package manager.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to instal it in a MiKTeX distribution (adapted from the package documentation, which is a bit obsolete).

First,, you need a  `TeXMF` local root, say  a directory `LocalTeXMF/`. If you don't have already one, create it,and validate  it with `MiKTeX Settings (Admin)`, `Roots` tab, `Add…` button, like this:

[image]

This local root has to be organised according to the `TeX Directory Structure` (TDS). In the present case, you have to create the following subdirectories:

1. `LocalTeXMF\fonts\source\`, which will contain `morse10.mf`, `morse.alf`, `morse.num` and `morse.def`.
2. `LocalTeXMF\fonts\tfm\`, which will contain `morse10.tfm`
3. `LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\morse\`, for `morse.sty`.
4. `LocalTeXMF\doc\latex\morse\`, for `morsedoc.pdf`.

The remaining files are not useful. However, you may try to compile `morsedoc.tex`, which is the sourse code for `morsedoc.pdf` to check everything works fine, *after the last operation* : refresh the FNBD via `MiKTeX Settings (Admin)` again, `General` tab.

Be aware you'll obtain only `bitmap` fonts, as there is no type 1, true type or open type font.

Comment: Hi, I will use your procedure to install new fonts. +1

Comment: @SEbastiano: For  type 1 fonts, it is slightly  more complex.  In particular, under MiKTeX, one often has to run `updmap`.

Comment: I have installed myself with `updmap` the clone of `Optima` and `mtpro2 lite`. I have written on a paper the procedure. However you are a very very good user.